# Deleting duplicate Names from NamesManager using C# Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am facing some problem with deleting Names from NAmesManager in C# code.
As per my requirement, I need to delete all the Invalid names from the Names Manager. I am currently checking for the value of the Name and deleting it if the value is "#REF!". This is the code I am using

```
foreach (Name RangeName in namesManager2)
                {

                    if(RangeName.Value.Contains("#REF!")) 
                    {
                        RangeName.Delete();
                    }
                 }
```

The code works fine, However There are some strange situations where there exists 2 names with same Name but the scope is different. 
Consider cell 1 is named "TESTNAME" with scope of "Workbook" and cell 2 is also named "TESTNAME" with scope "Sheet1". The name referring to Cell2 has a valid value.

So when I am looping if the name with "#REF!" value is encountered the above code is removing both the names. I want to retain the name with valid value but delete only the invalid Name.

Can someone suggest how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

There are bugs with duplicated Local/global names.
Accessing a global name whilst the active sheet has an identically named name local to that sheet, will change the properties of the local name and NOT the global name, even if the name is fully qualified with the workbook name.

So to bypass this you have to:
- detect if the Name is a duplicate
- if so switch to a worksheet that is not the parent of the local name (of course there may be multiple local names, one on each sheet so the only really safe way is to add another temporary worksheet and switch to that)
- then access whichever name you want either in the Workbook Name collection or the worksheet name collection.

This is the technique used by the freebie Name Manager Addin developed by JK Pieterse and myself:
[Name manager Download](http://www.decisionmodels.com/downloads.htm)
 which has a lot more function than the built-in Name Manager

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use unique names for Name Ranges to avoid this sort of problem.

```
var activeBook = (Workbook)currentInstance.ActiveWorkbook;
Range rnArea = activeSheet.Range["A1:A1"];
activeBook.Names.Add("TESTNAME", rnArea);
rnArea = activeSheet.Range["B1:B1"];
activeSheet.Names.Add("TESTNAME", rnArea);

List<Name> existingNamedRangeList1 = XlHelper.GetNamedRanges(currentInstance.ActiveWorkbook);
foreach (Name RangeName in existingNamedRangeList1)
{
    if (RangeName.Value.Contains("#REF!"))
    {
        RangeName.Delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have actually tried this but for some reason it always deletes the valid one. I always see the valid one appears before the invalid name. Let me try again

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it looks like it assumes the Name will be unique, and as such any Deletes done will not have expected behaviour. One way to get around this is to generate a unique name when going through all the RangeNames, then after you are done deleting, reset them back to their original names.

```
var rangeNameHolder = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var rangeNames = activeBook.Names;
int counter = 0;
foreach (Name rangeName in rangeNames)
{
    var oldName = rangeName.Name;
    /*
     * This hack here is done because when you grab the name, it includes the prepended scope. 
     * However, when you set the name, it prepends the scope yet again! 
     * So when you grab it the first time you need to remove the scope so that it doesnt get
     * prepended twice
     */
    oldName =oldName.Substring(oldName.LastIndexOf('!')+1);
    var newName = string.Format("{0}{1}", oldName, counter++);
    rangeName.Name = newName;
    if (rangeName.Value.Contains("#REF!"))
    {
        rangeName.Delete();
        continue;
    }
    rangeNameHolder.Add(rangeName.Name,oldName);
}

//Reset names back to original
foreach (Name rangeName in rangeNames)
{
    if (rangeNameHolder.ContainsKey(rangeName.Name))
        rangeName.Name = rangeNameHolder[rangeName.Name];
}
```